# Android Wear Emulator not working on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-emulator

I'm trying to get started in the Android Wear development program and create a simple app, but I can't seem to get the emulator started.  I followed all the steps on here : http://developer.android.com/wear/preview/start.html

and created the avd in the virtual device manager, but I keep getting this error

Starting emulator for AVD 'AndroidWearRound'
Failed to start emulator: Cannot run program "/home/brian/Development/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140321/sdk//tools/emulator": error=2, No such file or directory

Anyone run into this same problem or have any ideas?﻿

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check
  http://dandar3.blogspot.mx/2014/03/android-sdk-tools-on-ubuntu-1404-beta.html

$ sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6

Have a nice day!

Comment: Could you add a bit of explanation, link only answers are frowned upon. Thanks!